# Sed multiple conditions regex matching

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am making a bash script that will take a txt file as input, delete all lines containing dash ("-") or any integer (anywhere in the line) from it and parse it to a new file.

I tried multiple ways but I had 0 success.

I'm stuck trying to figure out correct regex for "delete all lines containing number OR dash" since I can't make it work.

Here's my code:

```
wget -q awsfile1.csv.zip                      # downloads file
unzip "awsfile1".zip                          # unzips it
cut -d, -f 2 file1.csv > file2.csv            # cuts it
sort file2.csv > file2.txt                    # translates csv into text
printf "Removing lines containing numbers.\n" # prints output
sed 's/[0-9][0-9]*/Number/g'  file2.txt > file2-b.txt  # doesn't do anything, file is empty on the output
```

Thanks.

Comment: adding a few details might get you better help.. 1) add input sample file with few lines, some that should be in output and some that shouldn't 2) complete expected output for the said sample 3) add at least one command/script that you tried, describe your logic if possible

Comment: Somithing like `grep -Ev -- "--|[0-9]"` ?

Comment: This is not bash regex matching, it's `sed` regex matching. `sed` is a separate external tool, not part of bash; it works the same way no matter what shell you use (bash/zsh/dash/etc).

Comment: BTW, we ask that code samples be in [mcve] format so other people can run them to see the problem. If you use comments that aren't valid syntax, obviously, nobody can use the code without changing it first; thus, the edit removing the `**`s for emphasis, and changing the `/` comments to `#`s.

Comment: what is `$day1.txt`, did you mean `file2.txt`?  Also the `sed` script will not delete the lines contrary to your intention.

Comment: yeah, forgot to change it when i pasted code here. i meant printing in reverse, i think most got the point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can combine cut and filter into an `awk` script and sort after

```
... get and unzip file
$ awk -F, '$2!~/[-0-9]/{print $2}' file | sort
```

print field 2 if it doesn't contain any digits or hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'h;s/\S+/\n&\n/2;/\n.*[-0-9].*\n/d;x' file
```

Copy the current line, isolate the 2nd field and delete the line if it contains the required strings, otherwise revert to the original line.

N.B. This prints the original line, if you only want the 2nd field, use:

```
sed -E 's/\S+/\n&\n/2;s/.*\n(.*)\n.*/\1/;/[-0-9]/d' file
```